# Is an occasional 10ms delay okay for 60 fps?

Tags: c#, xna

In my XNA game, I have an operation which takes about 10ms on my computer (2.5 Ghz dual core Intel Centrino 2) in debug mode. It will only be run once every several minutes, and it is basically nothing but integer math/bitwise operations, albeit a lot.

Can I call this directly in my Update method, or will it cause too much lag? The rest of my Update method shouldn't take more than 5ms (not created yet, so can't profile). I could also split it into several frames, as long as all the steps are called in order.

The main question is: Is this worth creating a separate thread for, or will the delay be irrelevant at 60fps?

Comment: So, you basically want us to guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a separate thread for anything that could cause a drawing delay if possible. As your game grows and gains new features, it's better to have kept performance in mind all along rather than going back through the code and attempt to decouple elements that could have been designed better from the start.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a separate thread, if the code is FPS critical, and you can't guarantee how long the code will take... and... it's not important to rendering a frame.

It might take 10ms on your system, but what about other systems? and even that might cause noticeable jitters sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Lets check the math

```
60 Frames per second = 16.666(ms) theoretically available per frame.
```

Now depending on what else you are doing per frame, this could be acceptable.

More importantly, is this operation critical to future frames?

If so, you don't have much choice (other than optimizing it as much as possible).

If not, then you should spawn a seperate thread for this operation.

Comment: 'Critical to future frames' - yes, but I can just pause the game, as this is a level generation, and the user won't mind having to wait 10 frames for a new level.

Comment: It might be optimal then to generate this much more in advance in a sperate thread.  I'm going to assume that you have a Diablo-ish game where ever the player goes outside the "normal start area" is random.  You could simply, at the beginning, generate all the levels then start playing, as diablo does.

Comment: This would take a lot of memory, not like it would be GB, but it might be slow.

Comment: Just a suggestion based on another game that does something similar.  It may or may not be the best choice, I wouldn't really know with the limited information provided.  As for memory, since you are using XNA, the minimum Xbox 360 has 512mb and Windows Phone 7 minimum spec is 256mb.